# If $S\leq G$, prove that $S\unlhd G \iff \gamma (S) \leq S$ for every conjugation $\gamma$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

If $S\leq G$, prove that $S\unlhd G \iff \gamma (S) \leq S$ for every conjugation $\gamma$

I have proven the forward direction but I am not sure that the way I prove the converse is true.

Let $g\in G,s\in S$.
$$gsg^{-1}=s_1,s_1\in S$$
$$\implies gs=s_1g$$
$$\implies gS \subset Sg$$
Also,
$$sg^{-1}=g^{-1}s_1$$
$$\implies Sg^{-1}\subset g^{-1}S$$
Hence, $Sg=gS$ and $S$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: Just check that all the implications are reversible.

Comment: How does $gs=s_1g$ imply $gS\subset Sg$? Perhaps you are missing sume quantification.

Comment: @anon This equation holds for every s right?

Comment: Right. Like I said, missing some quantification. If for every $s\in S$ there is a $s'\in S$ for which $gs=s'g$ (hence $gs\in Sg$), then in particular we have $gs\in Sg$ for every $s\in S$, hence $gS\subseteq Sg$.

Comment: @anon Ok noted. Then does $Sg^{-1}\subset g^{-1}S$ implies $Sg\subset gS$? I am not pretty sure with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but I think the proof would be clearer if you used the same $g$ for the cosets.

For the backwards inclusion, you could write:

Let $sg \in Sg$. Since $g^{-1}sg \in S$ (because $S$ is normal), we have $g^{-1}sg=s'$ for some $s'\in S$.

Hence, $sg = gs' \in gS$, so $Sg \subseteq gS$.